# subsets of an infinite countable set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Assume $X = \{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots \}$ is an infinite countable set. Let us write it as a union of disjoint sets:

$$
X = \bigcup_{i=1}^{s}X_{i},
$$

for some $s \leq \infty$. My question: are there countably many ways to write the original set as a union of disjoint sets?

Answer (score 3):

There are in fact uncountably many ways of writing a countable set as a disjoint union of subsets. Indeed, for each subset $A \subseteq X$ with $|A| \ge 2$, we can write
$$X = A \cup \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus A} \{ x \}$$
These partitions are distinct since $A$ can be detected as being the only non-singleton in the partition. Since there are uncountably many subsets of $X$ of size $\ge 2$, the result follows.